# Error while installing pip install pgadmin4-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, pip, pgadmin

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying to install `pgadmin4` with

```
pip install pgadmin4-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

But received the following error while installing pgadmin4:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6FWQnT/psycopg2/
```

[image]

Can someone please assist or give advice on how to rectify this error?

Also, I tried to find the

```
config_locale.py
```

file in order to configure the file in accordance with this sites instructions, but there was no such file.  Should I post another query or may I ask if someone can help me to locate the file?

Answer (score 1):

I have also facing this issue today. at first  psycopg2==2.6.2 have some bug/issues, that's why we were faceing this type of issues. so you need to install latest version of psycopg2 by using following command.

```
pip install  pgadmin4-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl  -U psycopg2
```

This command will install all the dependencies and install upgraded version of psycopg2.

Secondly  config_locale.py file will create after this installation process complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands

Install for both desktop and web modes:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

Install for desktop mode only:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop
```

Install for web mode only:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4-web
```

You can refer to the below documentation:
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 22.04 follow these steps:

download package

```
curl  -fsSL https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pgadmin.gpg
```

add pgAdmin repository in your Ubuntu system

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list'
```

update the package lists

```
sudo apt update
```

install pgadmin4

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

Apache service should have been started after installation
check it works

```
systemctl status apache2
```

configure pgadmin4

```
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```

the credentials are for your account - not any database

allow http and https traffic through UFW

```
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
```

Open your browser to
**http://127.0.0.1/pgadmin4**

Login by using email address and password you set before, then configure your server.

[source](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-on-ubuntu/)